# 3D or 4D Numpy array indexed using 2D mask & entire matrix operation

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to do some operation on an entire 3D or 4D array, but only on subgroups of smaller size (2D array contained in the bigger array).

Example:

```
input = np.arange(75).reshape((3, 5, 5))  # or any other 3D or 4D matrix. 
mask_hor = np.arange(-1, 2)
mask_ver = mask_hor[:, None]

output = np.zeros((3, 3, 3))

for i in range(1, 5):
  for j in range(1, 5):
    output[:, i-1, j-1] = foo(input[:, i+mask_ver, j+mask_hor])
```

where foo is some sort of manipulation of the input

My question is:
Is there a method / mask which I can pass to the input such that I can get rid of the nested for loops? I am looking for a speedup mainly.

Thank you!

Comment: Looks like you want to have sliding windows along the last two axes. So, you can use skimage : `from skimage.util.shape import view_as_windows, 
out = view_as_windows(input, (1,3,3))`. Then, use `foo` along the last two axes of `out`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Yes, i totally forgot that term exists (sliding window). This solves half of my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a quick and dirty optimization than anything elegant. For the sake of argument we're going to sum the 9 elements in the window as our `foo` function.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage

# take the sum of a 3x3 window of a matrix
def foo_lin_mat(mat):
    return mat.sum(axis=(-2, -1))  # sum over the last two axes

# sum up the individual matrices
def foo_lin_nine(m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, m6, m7, m8, m9):
    return m1 + m2 + m3 + m4 + m5 + m6 + m7 + m8 + m9

# compute foo on an input matrix by shifting the mask around
def nestfor(input, foo):
    depth, n, m = input.shape
    output = np.zeros((depth, n - 2, m - 2))
    mask_hor = np.arange(-1, 2)
    mask_ver = mask_hor[:, None]
    for i in range(1, n - 1):
        for j in range(1, m - 1):
            output[:, i - 1, j - 1] = foo(input[:, i + mask_ver, j + mask_hor])
    return output

# compute foo on an input matrix by breaking the input matrix into 9 submatrices 
def flatargs(input, foo):
    depth, n, m = input.shape
    return foo(input[:, :n-2, :m-2], 
               input[:, 1:n-1, :m-2],
               input[:, 2:, :m-2],
               input[:, :n-2, 1:m-1],
               input[:, 1:n-1, 1:m-1],
               input[:, 2:, 1:m-1],
               input[:, :n-2, 2:],
               input[:, 1:n-1, 2:],
               input[:, 2:, 2:], )

# compute the sum of a window using ndimage.convolve
def convolve(input, mask):
    mask = np.ones((1, 3, 3))
    out = ndimage.convolve(input, mask)
    # cut off the outer edges
    return out[1:-1, 1:-1]
```

So we've got three functions that'll take a matrix and sum up individual 3x3 windows. I've confirmed that they spit out the same matrix at the end. As for benchmarking

```
In [62]: %timeit  nestfor(input, foo_lin_mat)
1000 loops, best of 3: 261 µs per loop

In [63]: %timeit flatargs(input, foo_lin_nine)
10000 loops, best of 3: 35.8 µs per loop

In [66]: mask = np.ones((1,3,3))

In [69]: %timeit convolve(input, mask)
The slowest run took 6.12 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000 loops, best of 3: 42.2 µs per loop
```

I.e. the `flatargs` version is about 7x faster than the original, nested for-loop, version.

If your `foo` function is linear function of the input windows, you can also use the `ndimage.convolve` function to do the windowing, as in the `convolve` function here. It might be a bit easier to read the final code, but you would have to be careful of the what array you use for the mask.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! That can work. Only problem is that my mask is variable. I could adapt the code so for each part, I have different section with exact values. But that would just make the code increasingly longer, for no reason. I can try something around.